# Simulate camera with stage + rviz?

Tags: gazebo, simulation, rviz, stage, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was able to follow [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/SimulatingOneRobot) tutorial successfully (simulating one robot with stage + rviz), so my next step would be, how could I simulate a camera in the robot?
I can add it in rviz, but there's no image source for it to be found. Is there any way I can include it somehow?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11413/simulate-camera-with-stage-+-rviz?/) by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2011-10-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Stage is a 2D simulator, so there is no way to simulate a camera. You should try [Gazebo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo) instead. There's a tutorial how to add a camera to your URDF [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/AddingSensorsToPR2).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not really true (any more)..

http://answers.ros.org/question/43238/using-stageros-and-a-simulated-camera/

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2